# How to cache pages with redis in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redis, servicestack.redis

I'm somehow beginner in redis and I know it is easy in redis if you want to cache list or object or something like that but I don't know how can I store my web pages in redis?
notice that I'm using servicestack as my redis client and for saving data  using service stack to my redis I'm using such code:

```
 IRedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient();
        var rc = redisClient.As<person>();
        rc.Store(new person()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "foo"
        });
        rc.Store(new person()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "bar"
        });
        var result = rc.GetAll();
```

as I told you before I have a big question in my mind that it is

**How can I cache my .html or .cshtml pages in .net core web application with using Redis?**

Answer (score 3):

The response caching middleware uses whatever distributed cache is configured. Therefore, you need to add the [Redis distributed cache provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.1#using-a-redis-distributed-cache), and then add the [response caching middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "localhost";
    options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
});
services.AddResponseCaching();
```

FWIW, you should also change your existing code to utilize an injected instance of `IDistributedCache`, rather than working with `RedisClient` directly. The end result will be the same (assuming you've configured Redis as your distributed cache provider), but you'll abstract the implementation out of your code.

Comment: Could you refer to an official documentation where it states that the middleware can use any distributed cache, please?

Comment: See some issues around this 
A. [not possible to plug Redis in](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2957)
B. [current state of response caching](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27387)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ServiceStack Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net/) or [ServiceStack Templates](http://templates.servicestack.net/) to generate your Views you can use the [[CachedResponse] attribute](http://docs.servicestack.net/cacheresponse-attribute) to cache the Output responses of your Services, e.g:

```
[CacheResponse(Duration = 60)]
public class CachedServices : Service 
{ 
    public object Any(GetCustomer request) { ... }

    public object Any(GetCustomerOrders request) { ... }
}
```

Annotating your Service will cache the output response of all Services, otherwise you can add them on service implementation methods to cache them adhoc, e.g:

```
public class CachedServices : Service 
{ 
    public object Any(GetCustomer request) { ... }

    [CacheResponse(Duration = 60)]
    public object Any(GetCustomerOrders request) { ... }
}
```